# Parse multiple xml nodes and child-nodes inside global node?

Tags: c#, xml

How i can parse multiple nodes & child nodes in one XML file? 
Here the file structure:

```xml
<objects>

 <object id=1 name="test" param="1">
   <attribute key = "test" value="1"/>

   <subobjects>
    <subobject id=2 value="test" param="some"/>
    <subobject2 id=2 value="test" param="some"/>
    <subobject3 id=2 value="test" param="some"/>
   </subobjects>

 </object>

 <object id=2 name="newtest" param="44">
   <attribute key = "test1" value="1"/>
   <attribute key = "test2" value="2"/>
   <attribute key = "test3" value="3"/>

   <subobjects>
    <subobject id=1 value="intvaluetest" param="1"/>
   </subobjects>

 </object>

</objects>
```

I am try to make a reader-parser for this, and him sucessufy reads object and attribute keys,
but i dont have idea, how i can read  node and their children nodes in this format (as on xml example)
My reader is:

```cs
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(fileName);

    foreach (XmlNode node in document.GetElementsByTagName("object"))
    {
        ushort id = ushort.Parse(node.Attributes["id"].InnerText);
        //do some things

        foreach (XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
        {
            switch (attr.Name.ToLower())
            {
                case "name":
                    //do things
                    break;
                case "param":
                    //do things
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode attrNode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (attrNode.Attributes != null &&
                    attrNode.Attributes.Count > 0 &&
                    attrNode.Attributes["key"] != null &&
                    attrNode.Attributes["value"] != null)
                {
                    string value = attrNode.Attributes["value"].InnerText;
                    switch (attrNode.Attributes["key"].InnerText.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "test":
                            //do things with value
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Please, any solution in C# for XML parse nodes and child nodes in this case? I think `nodeList=root.SelectNodes()` - non better idea in this cause. `<subobjects>` - is children node of object, and this have a their non-static (for each object - different) type of sub-object. Any idea?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) instead of XmlDocument (before I give a complete answer that uses XDocument)?

Comment: there is no specific reason for XmlDocument. But i will be happy to see, how to do this on XDocument too! Learning - never too late.

Comment: You know you can use XPath to select nodes...right?  XmlNodeList MyNodes = XDoc.SelectNodes("//subobject2 | //subobject3");

Comment: What do you want for the output?  You have shown the attempt to collection values, but not what you except the output to be.

Comment: I will read this data, and add each object and their sub-objects to list of objects. Each object have id, and other params, few attributes and sub-objects for dictionary in class.

Comment: Well, XPath is useful, but how about little explain? What for example, if not any object, contains subobject3 in <subobjects> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a recursive function work?

```
static void Main() {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("test.xml");

    ReadNode(doc.GetElementsByTagName("object")[0]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void ReadNode(XmlNode node) {
        //Do something with each Node
        if(node.Attributes.Count > 0) {
            foreach(XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes) {
                //Do Something with each Attribute
            }
        }
        if(node.HasChildNodes == true) {
            foreach(XmlNode chlnode in node.ChildNodes) {
                ReadNode(chlnode);
            }
        }
    }
```

You could use `XmlNode.Name` to know which node you're dealing with.

Comment: Yeah, thats idea by using recusive mode. I will try this.